# How can you use mapbox-gl-Draw to create rectangle of 8 points?

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl-draw

I have a unique issue to using Mapbox-gl-Draw. Mapbox Draw allows you to create a multi point polygon easily, however I need it to use only 8 points as an algorithm i use elsewhere accepts 8 lnglat elements. Im wondering if it is possible that when the draw button is clicked, that it displays a rectangle of 8 points on screen with the ability to drag each of the points?

Below is the expected outcome with one click of draw.
[image: Expected outcome]
Currently i can draw a rectangle but with only 4 points, each corner of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to mess with mapbox-gl-draw, you should just take the output, then add the midpoints programmatically. You can use [turf's `midpoint`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#midpoint) function for that purpose. Something like:

```
const coords = rectangle.geometry.coordinates[0];
const newcoords = [];
coords.forEach((point, i) => {
   newcoords.push(point);
   if (i < coords.length - 1) {
       newcoords.push(midpoint(point, coords[i+1]).geometry.coords);
   }
});
rectangle.geometry.coordinates = newcoords;
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, your answer is spot on, after much messing about i came up with the solution. I wish i had have posted this question sooner.